# c# smart way to delete multiple occurance of a character in a string

Tags: c#, list, split

My program reads a file which has thousands of lines of something like this below
"Timestamp","LiveStandby","Total1","Total2","Total3", etc..
each line is different
What is the best way to split by , and delete the "" as well as put the values in a list

this is what I have

```
 while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
     List<string> title_list = new List<string>(line.Split(',')); 
  }
```

the step above still missing the deletion of the quotes. I can do foreach but that kinda defeat the purpose of having  List and Split in just 1 line. What is the best and smart way to do it?

Comment: Two words: regular expressions

Comment: @Al - where should I apply this? I dont think I can overload the Split?

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems." - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: @John Can you please clarify if this is a user generated or a system generated file? It's pretty clear that there are a lot of ways to approach this (ie some people only have a hammer and everything looks like a nail). If it is a user generated file, then the CSV parser is definitely way to go. Simpler solutions such as Cheeso and mine are great for system generated data where you just want to remove very specific characters. Please clarify.

Comment: To clarify my above comment: Regular expressions isn't best approach. It is easieest possible solution (expecting one uses it often so he/she knows how to use it).

Comment: @hatchet As far as the CSV file specification goes, those are not headers. Their presence or absence isn't really the issue here; The important point is whether or not the fields have escaped commas or quotes contained within them.

Comment: @AndrewBarber-Fair enough..I'll try again. Is your example a description of what each line contains (i.e. every line has a timestamp value in the first column), or a literal example of a line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping it simple like this should work:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) 
    string.AddRange(line.Replace("\"").split(',').AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: @naspinski - ToEnumerable is not available? I am missing something?

Comment: I have System.Linq. still not available.I am on .NET3.5

Comment: What if there are commas inside strings? In that case this fails, doesn't it?

Comment: yes, but you could always do a different split as well: .Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.IgnoreEmptyEntries)

Comment: title_list.AddRange(line.Replace("\"","").Split(',').AsEnumerable());

Comment: I like this solution. It's very very simple and for this particular problem it's the best for me

Comment: lol. I had a similar one at first and all the smarty pants banging on about csv parsing made me change it. Glad you got your answer anyway :D

Answer (score 4):

The best way in my opinion is to use a library that parses [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), such as [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/).

Concretely, in your case, this would be the solution using the FileHelpers library:

Define a class that describes the structure of a record:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class MyDataRecord
{
    [FieldQuoted('"')]
    public string TimeStamp;
    [FieldQuoted('"')]
    public string LiveStandby;
    [FieldQuoted('"')]
    public string Total1;
    [FieldQuoted('"')]
    public string Total2;
    [FieldQuoted('"')]
    public string Total3;
}
```

Use this code to parse the entire file:

```
var csvEngine = new FileHelperEngine<MyDataRecord>(Encoding.UTF8)
    { 
        Options = { IgnoreFirstLines = 1, IgnoreEmptyLines = true }
    };

var parsedItems = csvEngine.ReadFile(@"D:\myfile.csv");
```

*Please note that this code is for illustration only and I have not compiled/run it. However, the library is pretty straightforward to use and there are good examples and documentation on the website.*

Comment: The OP never really said it was a regular CSV file. He did say each line was different. That could mean 10 strings in line 1, 20 strings in line 2, etc.

Comment: @hatchet while it is true that OP never mentioned "CSV", the presented case looks very similar to a CSV file. "Every line is different" may also mean that each line has new values or the `","` do not necessarily align, in order to be parsed out more easily

Comment: @Andrew: I can't see any Regex solutions here. Only Replace/Split solutions which are really basic and not good. Regex can do better, but it's slow.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to clarify this a bit. If you have a user formatted file that has a predictable format (ie the user has generated the data out of EXCEL or similar program) then you are way better off using an exising parser that is well tested.

Scenarios like the following are just a few examples that manual parsing will have problems with:

```
"column 1", 2, 0104400, $1,300, "This is an interestion question, he said"
```

.. and there are more with escaping, file formats etc that can be a headache for roll your own.

If you do that, then ensure you get one that can tollerate differences in columns per row as it can make a difference.

If, on the other hand, you know what's going into the data which is common in system generated files then using CSV parsers will cause more problems than they solve. For example, I have dealt with scenarios where the first part is fixed and can be strongly typed, but there are following parts in a row that are not. This can also happen if you're parsing flat file data in fixed width scenarios from legacy databases. A csv solution makes assumptions we don't want and is not the right solution in many of those cases.

If that is the case and you just want to strip out quotes after splitting on commas, then try a bit of linq. This can also be extended to replace specific characters you are worried about.

```
line.Split(',').Select(i => i.Replace("\"", "")).ToArray()
```

Hope that clears up all the conflicting advice.

Comment: Thanks for that Andrew, but I was assuming he knew what he was doing and how to extend this to remove the specific characters he wanted to remove. I could on the other hand write out my CSV parser helpers, but then he wouldn't learn anything would he?

Comment: Using a cv parser is a valid suggestion, but not garanteed to be the answer he is looking for.

Comment: Ok fellas. Answer updated to take this ASSUMPTION into account. Fact is I assumed the question was literal, and some assumed the question was dealing with a scenario he has not specified in the question. Both can be right... consider it cleared up. No mention of CSV in his question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Array.ConvertAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) function.

```
string line = "\"Timestamp\",\"LiveStandby\",\"Total1\",\"Total2\",\"Total3\"";

var list = new List<String>(Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(','), x=> x.Replace("\"","")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform the Replace first, then Split into your List.  Here's your code with Replace.

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)   
{      
  List<string> title_list = new List<string>(line.Replace("\"", "").Split(','));    
}
```

Although, you're going to need a variable to hold all of the Lists, so look at using AddRange().